# Most Efficient Way to Store and Access Data with Multiple Attributes

Tags: c++

I've been racking my brain over the past several days trying to find a solution to a storage/access problem.

I currently have 300 unique items with 10 attributes each (all attributes are currently set as strings but some of the attributes are numerical). I am trying to programmatically store and be able to efficiently access attributes based on item ID. I have *attempted* storing them in string arrays, vectors, maps, and multimaps with no success.

**Goal:** to be able to quickly access an item and one of its attributes quickly and efficiently by unique identifier.

The closest I have been able to get to being successful is:

```
string item1[] = {"attrib1","attrib2","attrib3","attrib4","attrib5","attrib6","attrib7","attrib8","attrib9","attrib10"};
```

I was then able to access an element on-demand by calling`item1[0];` but this is VERY inefficient (particularly when trying to loop through 300 items) and was very hard to work with.

Is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: How is accessing an array by index "VERY inefficient"? Efficient in what sense? Oh, do you actually mean that you were considering writing 300 different string array variables, named `item1` through `item300`?

Comment: Well I had already written all 300 string array variables (thank god for Notepad++ & regex). I suppose I should have phrased it as would it be better to leave the arrays as-is or would it be easier creating a class which would somehow handle function calls?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I just looked up the documentation for unordered map and it appears from what I've read that `unordered_map` supports duplicate keys, which is what I would need if it's able to support 10 values per key. Would it be possible for you to provide some boilerplate `unordered_map` code?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly it sounds like you should have some sort of class to hold the attributes, which you would put into a map that has the item ID as the key.

Comment: "I have attempted storing them in string arrays, vectors, maps, and multimaps with no success."

Comment: Such an incredibly broad statement leads me to believe that it's being done wrong then. Unless he's leaving out important details of his problem, this seems pretty straight forward.

Comment: I admit that I feel I'm doing it wrong as I'm not sure exactly how to approach how it should be done that makes it scaleable without too much modification. I didn't leave out any functional information.